# Watir /Cucumber Unable to locate element : dd-field div.dd-arrow-box (Using CSS Selector*

Tags: css, selector, watir

**Chief complaint:**

Using CSS Selector cannot locate element

**Css path:**

```
html.ng-scope body.ng-scope div.snap-content div.content-container div.ng-scope div.content-box div div.cb-landing-module div.deposit-acct-box div.dropdown div.dd-field div.dd-arrow-box
```

**Css selector:**

```
.dropdown .dd-arrow-box
```

**How I used it in Watir/Cucumber :**

```
@browser.element(:css => 'dd-arrow-box').click
```

**Error:**

> Cucumber reported error: Unable to late element

**Description Of Problem:**

I have a combo box of sorts that I would like to click
The result  would be selecting items from the list.
I have tried xpath , in may combinations  with the same error
Unable to find element

**Tried:**

Possible / sync  issue: Fire on Even …. *Failed*

Xpath – *Failed*

When I take the method off ( e.g ) click away and add exist it is found . I can’t click it

Edit: Adding HTML from Comment:

```
      <div class="dd-arrow">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div> 
<ul class="dd-box" style="display: none;"> 
  <li class="dd-list-head"> Direct Deposit </li> 
  <li class="dd-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="selectAccount(directDeposit)" ng-repeat="directDeposit in directDeposits"> 
  <span class="acct-name ng-binding">WELLS FARGO BANK, NA</span>
```

Still puzzled the last threw the following exception: invalid attribute: :css (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException)

Comment: Is your element inside a frame? I recall being befuddled by watir not finding something i could clearly see and select with jquery from dev tools console... If it is inside a frame, something like `@browser.frame(:name, 'FrameName').element(:css => 'dd-arrow-box').click` would do the trick :P

Answer (score 0):

This might be because what you are looking for is the `dd-arrow-box` tag, not the class. Change your code to look like this:

```
@browser.element(:css => '.dd-arrow-box').click
```

exactly like you would if you were defining a css file. Notice the period in front of `dd-arrow-box`

Here's a good example.
Given the html:

```
<div class="divhere">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

you could use the code `@browser.element(css: 'p').text` to grab the text from the paragraph.

Likewise, `@browser.element(css: '.divhere')` will locate the div element using the class selector.

Comment: Thanks for your prompts response. I did use the example you suggested "browser.element(:css => '.dd-arrow-box').click " But I got the same error. This is so odd because firebug is highlighting the element that I am need. The element is not in a frame.

Comment: If you post the html it would help. In the meantime try changing it to  `@browser.element(css: 'div.dd-arrow-box').click`. Make sure you are putting the @browser in front. Also it would be more helpful if you could post the rest of the code, and not just the error message and a snippet.

Comment: You could also try changing the call to `@browser.div(css: 'div.dd-arrow-box').click`

Comment: <div class="dd-arrow"></div>

Comment: </div>
</div>
<ul class="dd-box" style="display: none;">
<li class="dd-list-head"> Direct Deposit </li>
<li class="dd-item ng-scope

Comment: g-binding" ng-click="selectAccount(directDeposit)" ng-repeat="directDeposit in directDeposits">
<span class="acct-name ng-binding">WELLS FARGO BANK, NA</span>
  (0001)

Comment: Still puzzled the last threw the following exception:      invalid attribute: :css (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException)

Comment: You should update your post instead of trying to post the html in a comment. It looks like you are using the wrong css selector. Are you trying to choose the `<div class="dd-arrow"></div>`? Then you need to use `@browser.div(css: '.dd-arrow').click` You should edit your post to reflect what errors you are seeing and what the code you are using is.